# How to send cUrl JSON request to Yii2 api using greater/less than operators

Tags: php, json, api, curl, yii2

As an example of cUrl request targeting yii2 restfull web service I have this command:

`curl -i -H "Accept:application/xml" "http://localhost/api/users"`

But I want to get users with the id between 100 and 250 ( this is not part of pagination, it is just request like that ).

How should I specify this condition ?

I have tried this but it does not work:

`curl -i -H "Accept:application/xml" "http://localhost/api/users?id={"lt": 100, "gt": 30}"`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use pagination functionality of yii2 resfull controller, you can use `limit` and `offset` parameters. It is a bit similar to creating SQL queries.

For example, 
`curl -i -H "Accept:application/xml" "http://localhost/api/users?offset=100&limit=150`

and in your controller

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $limit = Yii::$app->request->post('limit', 20);
        $offset = Yii::$app->request->post('offset', 0);
        return new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => User::find()->limit($limit)->offset($offset),
        ]);
    }
}
```